# Bank Wait Times

Tags: probability

The time it takes to open a bank account is an exponential random variable with parameter 1.  Arthur and Beatrice meet at the same bank to open a bank account each. If Beatrice arrives at the bank at time 0 and Arthur arrives at the bank at time t≥0, what is the probability that Arthur is done before Beatrice?  (Assume that service times are independent and that Arthur and Beatrice are served by different clerks as soon as they arrive at the bank.)

I found a result that depends on t, the time after Beatrice arrives that Arthur arrives at the bank. But I feel that there should be a way to get an explicit probability, given that we are given the exact distribution of wait times. Do I need to condition on t?

Comment: The answer should definitely depend on $t$.  As $t$ goes to $0$, it should reduce to $1/2$, and as $t$ goes to infinity, the probability should go to zero, but in between the answer will depend on $t$.

Comment: Your answer should be in terms of $t$; that is perfectly fine. In fact, you should be worried if the answer didn't depend on $t$ as the probability that Arthur finishes first should not be very high if he arrived an hour after Beatrice versus if he arrived at the exact same time as Beatrice.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get an explicit probability without some knowledge of the distribution of *t*. We know Arthur arrives sometime after Beatrice, but that could be 1 minute, 1 hour, or 1 day, with no information about which of those it's likely to be. In absence of this information, all you can do is express the probability for each case, which is the expression dependent on *t* that you already found.

If you had some knowledge about the distribution of *t*, like that it itself is exponentially distributed with parameter 1, you could integrate over the likelihood of each *t* to get a single numerical value. If we know that the distribution of *t* is concentrated at 0 (it's likely they arrive at nearly the same time), Arthur will have a somewhat less than 50% chance of leaving first. If the distribution of *t* skews heavily to the right (Arthur is likely to arrive much later), then Arthur's chance of leaving first will tend toward 0%.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the memorylessness property of the exponential distribution, if Beatrice is still being served when Arthur arrives, then they each have probability $\frac12$ of leaving first

So if Arthur arrives at time $t$, the probability Beatrice has already left is $1-e^{-t}$, and so the overall probability Arthur leaves first is $\frac12 e^{-t}$ and the overall probability that Beatrice leaves first is $1-\frac12 e^{-t}$

You can extend this to Arthur's arrival time $T$ being random.  For example, if Arthur's arrival time is exponential with expectation $k$, then the overall probability Arthur leaves first is $\frac{1}{2k+2}$ and the overall probability that Beatrice leaves first is $\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}$